# Disable email user notifications

Tags: 8, users, emails

It's possible in Drupal 8 disable all users notifications? New account, forgot password, etc

I'm using one external tool to send these emails and I don't need these notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to make sure no emails are going out is to add

Mailcontrol (https://www.drupal.org/project/mailcontrol) which lets you specify what emails go out.

or

Maillog (https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) which logs all emails and has an option to not send any emails to users. This will prevent all emails from leaving the system and log them if needed. It was designed to test sites but works well in this use case also.

Your other option is to go through and handle them one by one via code. There is no easy button inside of Drupal that will just turn off the service that I know of.

Sorry to just recommend a module, but given your needs this seems like a pretty obvious choice.

Comment: I'm currently using maillog (my preferred of the two) to prevent emails from going out that I handle via my decoupled React instance.

Comment: Hi Shawn, these modules don't are for Drupal 8. My web is in Drupal 8

Comment: Both have Drupal 8 versions. Mailcontrol -
 https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/mailcontrol-8.x-1.0.tar.gz Maillog - https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/maillog-8.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz

Comment: I'm currently using Maillog in a D8 environment. Its pretty far along for a dev release. Hope this helps @javiregpa.

Comment: Also mailsystem as mentioned by @kstack does the same thing as maillog, but appears to be further through its release cycle. It would probably be a better option if you are looking to log mail as well as prevent it from going out which is what it and maillog do. If you are looking to just turn it off I'd recommend mailcontrol.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use mailsystem module. [mailsytem](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem)

Then goto **Admin->Configuration->Mailsystem**  and select *Mail Collector* option in both **Formatter** and **Sender** .

This collect the mail within the drupal system without actually sending it.

More info: [Mail Collector](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Mail%21Plugin%21Mail%21TestMailCollector.php/class/TestMailCollector/8.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comprehensive set of solutions for addressing this problem in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8

[Managing mail handling for development or testing on a Drupal 7/8 Site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/managing-mail-handling-for-development-or-testing)